# Angular 2 HTTP GET method not returning any header with URL

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am not getting the URL headers with a token in HTTP GET method and also GET method showing OPTION angular 2 typescripts.

Please help me.Thanks

```
Component.ts
 onTestGet(Y)
    {
      var jwt = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      var k:string = localStorage.getItem(jwt);
      var authHeader = new Headers();
      authHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      if(k) {
        authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + k);      
          }
          return this._http.get('http://localhost:9095/api/v1/client/list?isClient=Y', {headers:authHeader})
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => alert(error),
             () => console.log("finished")
             );
      }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you are sending GET request, but on server you are receiving initially an OPTION request? If this is the case you are doing CORS (cross-origin HTTP request), meaning that you are calling server with different origin from the origin of your angular application. You can read more about CORS here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS or you should make the requests to the same origin.

Comment: Yes thanks,I have enabled cross domain plugin in google chrome,still i am getting same response,can i change anything in backend.

Comment: Yes. Your server should set correctly Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and probably Access-Control-Allow-Methods header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) to the response. Because you are sending Authorization header, your server also will need to set Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials headers

Comment: If it is still an CORS issue check your browser console. It will tell you if thats the problem.